# I can't boot from my optical drive on my Dell inspiron desktop

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, installation, optical-drive

My Dell Inspiron desktop was originally windows 10, but I decided to install linux on it, as that is what I prefer. Now, since I have a new computer, I decided to give the Inspiron to my parents (last time I went to their house I took a look inside their computer and found that almost all of the capacitors on the Mobo are on their last leg). They, however, don't want to use linux, so I was attempting to reinstall the original OS.

I have the windows 10 install disk, but every time I try to boot from it, it says there are no bootable devices available. In bios, I have the internal ODD selected as the first boot device, and I've disabled everything else (as it would automatically boot to linux even with the ODD selected as primary boot). Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get/how did you make the installation media? Are you sure the disk itself is actually marked as bootable? Does it work in any other machines?

Comment: It's a disk from dell that is supposed to work on any dell computer. I've already used it on a different computer. It booted to it, but it ultimately didn't work as that computer wasn't compatable with windows 10. This computer, though, certainly is compatable, but it won't boot to it.

Comment: Does the drive appear to attempt to read the disk during POST? If you enter the boot menu (F12 on most Dells I think?) and manually choose the optical drive, what happens?

Comment: Nothing. With the optical drive selected, once the boot sequence starts, it says no bootable device available. press F1 to retry boot.

Comment: The optical drive does appear to be trying to read the disk, though. I know the drive isn't malfunctioning, as I can read other cd's and dvd's from it since I've first tried. Also, I went and checked the bootable dvd on another computer, and it is still functioning properly.

Comment: Are there any BIOS settings described as "enable legacy boot", "enable UEFI boot", or "Boot mode" with a "UEFI" option? If so, fiddle with those.

Comment: I'll switch it to Legacy and try that. Although, the disk itself says to boot in UEFI mode, so I won't hold out hope. Get back to you shortly.

Comment: Nope. Same problem when I try it in Legacy boot.

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably just make a bootable flash drive. I've actually largely forgotten any optical drive tips/tricks/gotchas that I used to know :-P Although if that's challenging for whatever reason, I'd probably start doing the "change things that *should* make no difference dance", i.e. remove the drive, boot without it and save system settings, plug it back into a different SATA, that sort of thing